# How to get a button in Unity to connect to an Arduino RC Car?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino

I am currently working on a project where the game I am creating needs to connect to two RC cars (one is an Arduino RC car and the other is a Raspberry Pi RC car) through the use of a button.

I need the P1 button to connect to the Arduino RC Car and the P2 button to connect to the Raspberry Pi RC Car over the WiFi and change the red boxes to green, but the code I found over the Internet doesn't work.

I was wondering whether anyone would be able to help me and take a look because as I said earlier I have very limited experience and I can't figure out whats wrong with the following code -

```
using UnityEngine;                        // These are the librarys being used
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class ClientSocket : MonoBehaviour
{

    bool socketReady = false;                // global variables are setup here
    TcpClient mySocket;
    public NetworkStream theStream;
    StreamWriter theWriter;
    StreamReader theReader;
    public String Host = "INSERT the public IP of router or Local IP of Arduino";
    public Int32 Port = 5001;
    public bool lightStatus;


    void Start()
    {
        setupSocket();                        // setup the server connection when the program starts
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        while (theStream.DataAvailable)
        {                  // if new data is recieved from Arduino
            string recievedData = readSocket();
        }
    }

            // write it to a string


    public void setupSocket()
    {                            // Socket setup here
        try
        {
            mySocket = new TcpClient(Host, Port);
            theStream = mySocket.GetStream();
            theWriter = new StreamWriter(theStream);
            theReader = new StreamReader(theStream);
            socketReady = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Socket error:" + e);                // catch any exceptions
        }
    }

    public void writeSocket(string theLine)
    {            // function to write data out
        if (!socketReady)
            return;
        String tmpString = theLine;
        theWriter.Write(tmpString);
        theWriter.Flush();


    }

    public String readSocket()
    {                        // function to read data in
        if (!socketReady)
            return "";
        if (theStream.DataAvailable)
            return theReader.ReadLine();
        return "NoData";
    }

    public void closeSocket()
    {                            // function to close the socket
        if (!socketReady)
            return;
        theWriter.Close();
        theReader.Close();
        mySocket.Close();
        socketReady = false;
    }

    public void maintainConnection()
    {                    // function to maintain the connection (not sure why! but Im sure it will become a solution to a problem at somestage)
        if (!theStream.CanRead)
        {
            setupSocket();
        }
    }


} // end class
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"?

Comment: You can't just write a code and say it doesn't work. Which part does not work? It would make sense to post the Ardiuno code too. One advice to you is to start small by sending simple string to Arduino. Once that is done, you can then go ahead and continue writing longer codes.

Comment: Are you positive that you are using TCP and not UDP to communicate with the cars?

Answer (score 0):

Given the information we have here I'd say you first need an IP address of the raspberry pi. You need to fill it in between the quotes: "INSERT the public IP of router or Local IP of Arduino"
You are also not showing anything here. Try Debug.Log() the value "receivedData" in your Update() method.

What do the buttons do now? I'm guessing that you want them to writeSocket("forward(P1)") or something like that, so you can read that on the raspberry pi and drive some GPIO pins.

Arduino's can't connect to the internet out of the box. There are some solutions, but a few kb of memory won't get you very far.